# C++ which part of a vector is copied when passed to function

Tags: c++, vector

i got the following prototype

```
void Foo(const vector<uint8_t> vec);
```

now i was under the impression that only a pointer to the first element on the heap is copied to the functions stack. However while stepping through my code I'm not that sure any more. Before actually entering Foo i have to go through lots of new[] operators

Could it be possible that the whole vector (i.e all elements of this vector) are copied as well?

If so does the same thing apply for lists?

```
 void Foo(const List<uint8_t> ls);
```

Is the whole list copied as well?

Comment: It is not only possible, it is what actually happens.

Comment: Yes, the whole vector is copied. Declaring it this way`const vector<uint8_t> &vec` would only copy a reference to the vector.

Comment: When you do a pass of value, you are actually creating a new object and copying all the elements inside the vector. If you want to avoid the costly copy operations, then you need to use either move semantics or pass by reference. Sometimes the compiler optimizes these copy operations using RVO (or) NRVO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, argument copying means the whole vector is copied.

It you want a reference handed over, you can simple use:
`void Foo(const vector<uint8_t>& vec);`

Comment: Note that copy elision or the "as if" rule might kick in, resulting in no copy being made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you do a pass by value, the actual elements are being copied not the pointers.

Please see the example in the below link:

[copy_all_elements](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d57beeb05a4ef17e)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

void copy_all_elements(std::vector<uint8_t> vec_copy)
{
    vec_copy.push_back(70);
    std::cout<<"In copy_all_elements: ";
    for (auto i : vec_copy)
        std::cout<<(unsigned)i<<"\t";
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec{10,20,30,40,50};
    copy_all_elements(vec);
    vec.push_back(60);
    std::cout<<"In Main: ";
    for (auto i : vec)
        std::cout<<(unsigned)i<<"\t";
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Answer:

```
In copy_all_elements: 10    20  30  40  50  70  
In Main: 10 20  30  40  50  60
```

As you can see, both vectors are different because if the copy just copies the pointer then inserting an element into one vector should be reflecting in the other vector which is not happening here.

Also if you want to see what is the compiler doing exactly, you can generate the assembly code and check it.

```
lea     rdx, [rbp-112]
lea     rax, [rbp-80]
mov     rsi, rdx
mov     rdi, rax
call    std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::vector(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&)
lea     rax, [rbp-80]
mov     rdi, rax
call    copy_all_elements(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >)
lea     rax, [rbp-80]
mov     rdi, rax
call    std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::~vector() [complete object destructor]
```

Compiler: x86-64 gcc 8.2;
Standard: C++11;
Optimization: 0

I didn't use the optimization just to force the compiler to generate the code where it is actually creating a new vector.

Please copy the above program into the compiler explorer to see the complete assembly code generated [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: thx this site looks very interesting: I'll definatly have a look at it!